# Lucene index HTML File with Identifiers

Tags: java, lucene

first of all i wanna apologize for my poor english.
I have a html file named cacm.html with plenty of documents each document is structurated like this:

```
.I indicates article identifier
.T idicates article title
.A indicates article authors
.W indicates article resume
.X indicates article references
```

Here's an example of an Article:

```
.I 20
.T
Accelerating Convergence of Iterative Processes
.W
A technique is discussed which, when applied
to an iterative procedure for the solution of
an equation, accelerates the rate of convergence if
the iteration converges and induces convergence if
the iteration diverges.  An illustrative example is given.
.B
CACM June, 1958
.A
Wegstein, J. H.
.N
CA580602 JB March 22, 1978  9:09 PM
.X
20  5   20
20  5   20
20  5   20
```

i wrote this code:

```
    //IMPORTS

Public class in{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{  
    Path p = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\pc\\Desktop\\indexationeclipc", args);       
    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
    Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(p);
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
    IndexWriter iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\pc\\Desktop\\index\\cacm.htm"));

    boolean lire=false;

    String[] fields = new String[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        fields[i] = "";
    }
    int fieldno = 0;

    String line=br.readLine();
    while(line!=null) {
        if(line.startsWith(".I")) {


            String[] parts = line.split(" ");
            fields[0] = parts[1];
            fieldno = 0;



            if (!fields[0].equals("")) {
               Document doc=new Document();
               Field I= new StringField("I",fields[0],Field.Store.YES);
               doc.add(I);

               Field T= new StringField("T",fields[1],Field.Store.YES);
               doc.add(T);

               Field A= new StringField("A",fields[2],Field.Store.YES);
               doc.add(A);

               Field W= new TextField("W",fields[3],Field.Store.YES);
               doc.add(W);

               Field X= new TextField("X",fields[4],Field.Store.YES);
               doc.add(X);

               iwriter.addDocument(doc);

            }

             for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                 fields[i] = "";
             }


        }


        else if(line.startsWith(".T")) {
            lire=true;
            fieldno = 1;

        }

        else if(line.startsWith(".A")) {
            lire=true;
            fieldno = 2;
        }

        else if(line.startsWith(".W")) {
            lire=true;
            fieldno = 3;
        }

        else if(line.startsWith(".X")) {
            lire=true;
            fieldno = 4;
        }

        else if(line.startsWith(".")) {
            lire=false;
        }

        if((fieldno > 0) && (fieldno < 5)) {
            if(lire==true) {
            if (line.length() > 2) {
                fields[fieldno] += " " + line;
            }}
        }

        line = br.readLine();       

    }


br.close();
iwriter.close();


    }       
}
```

But the indexation isnt finishing,  the indexation stops and its not all the terms that get indexed and he indexed like a thousand time the same word and some times he indexes WHOLE Phrases not terms only :( x))

Comment: Title and Author should probably both be using `TextField`. Also, I'm not entirely sure I understand the format, but it looks to me like you are writing each document with the id from the next document.

Comment: I dont think im indexing docs with the next documents id, but i dont know why the first document dont get indexed too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not seams to be an indexing or lucene problem. I think there's a problem how you read this data and split it.

i would recommend using apache tika for html data extraction. It's pretty useful. See https://tika.apache.org/

Comment: I added Exception handling and still have the same problem, whats your suggesting for reading data ?

Comment: i'm not sure how your structure should look like at the end. do you wanna add all .T tags in one document or do you wanna have each article represented in the index like one document includes .I .T .A .W .X ?

Comment: I wanna have each article represented in the index like one document includes .I .T .A .W .X, this is what im trying to do in my code

Comment: i updated my answer. i think you should use apache tika for html extraction. so you do not have to care about all this splitting string things.

Comment: Im forced to use Lucene, its a school projet and im struck for more than a week x)

Comment: you have to use lucene for indexing, apache tika is just an additional framework to help extracting indexable data out of the html. have a look. it's worth it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171345/discussion-between-le-fragan-and-dom).